# differential equation with undetermined coefficient.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve differential equation with undetermined coefficient .I know how to solve when r(x)=sin x/ cos x .but not for it. what will be the particular solution for y"+9y=sec 3x?

Comment: What do you mean by     $sec 3x$

Comment: It must be $\dfrac{1}{\cos(3x)}.$

Comment: Where is the undetermined coefficient of your title ?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: make the ansatz
$$y_p=Ax\sin(3x)+B\cos(3x)\ln(\cos(3x))$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $y^{\prime \prime}(x)+P(x)y^\prime + Q(x)y=R(x)$. The general solution of this non-homogeneous equation has a neat expression

$$
y=y_2 \int \dfrac{Ry_1}{W}dx - y_1 \int \dfrac{Ry_2}{W}dx,
$$
with $W(x)=y_1y_2^\prime - y_2y_1^\prime$, the so-called Wronskian, and $y_1$, $y_2$ solutions of the homogeneous equation.

In your case $y_1=\sin(3x)$ and $y_2=\cos(3x)$, and  $W=-3$. Replace and perform the "trivial" integrals.

Comment: Use sparingly the adjective "trivial"... It adds no information and can sometimes be ill-perceived.

Comment: Good advice, thanks!